# ConstraintLayout with multiple widgets in each chain link

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

What's the right way to create a chain in a ConstraintLayout, in which each chain link has more than one widget?

This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

I'd like the chain to be: (easy button & score) === (medium button & score) === (hard button & score).

Obviously the traditional way of doing this would be to put each button & textview pair into its own layout, and chain those layouts. But my understanding is that ConstraintLayouts should avoid this: no layouts inside layouts, everything is flattened. Can it be done this way, or is the "flat layout" rule just not viable?

NB: This is simplified. My activity actually has many more components within the each group, so I'm looking for a general solution that isn't specific to, say, chain links of 2 components each.

My XML (in which the TextViews are completely unconstrained):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                                             tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_hard"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="50sp"
        android:paddingStart="50sp"
        android:text="@string/hard"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_medium"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_medium"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="50sp"
        android:paddingStart="50sp"
        android:text="@string/medium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_hard"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_easy"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_easy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:paddingEnd="50sp"
        android:paddingStart="50sp"
        android:text="@string/easy"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_medium"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Best score: 20"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="328dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Best score: 20"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="558dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Best score: 20"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="98dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this will help :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_hard"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="50sp"
        android:paddingStart="50sp"
        android:text="@string/hard"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_medium"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_medium"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="50sp"
        android:paddingStart="50sp"
        android:text="@string/medium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_easy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="50sp"
        android:paddingStart="50sp"
        android:text="@string/easy"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_medium"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Best score: 20"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.028"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_medium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Best score: 20"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.028"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_hard" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Best score: 20"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_menu_difficulty_easy" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's good and simple, but the TextViews aren't really part of the chain. Say for example if I had a packed chain, the TextViews wouldn't themselves resize. Or if there wasn't enough vertical space, the buttons would sit on top of the TextViews rather than things getting resized. Perhaps I'm asking too much...